# Writing a Python script to format data from .txt file

Tags: python, file, txt

I have a Python script that I want to use to read through a .txt file and return specific values. The file contains raw data that is not tabulated and hard to use - over 11,000 lines.

My script can return any input I provide, but I want the script to return the line beneath the one I input.

For example, if I type in the input: "SFCTEMP [K]"

I want the script to return every value in the file beneath string every time it comes up. I have indexed the lines but don't know how to achieve my desired outcome.

Here is the code:

```
file_name = input("Enter The File's Name: ")

# opening and reading the file
file_read = open(file_name, "r")

# asking the user to enter the string to be
# searched
text = input("Enter the String: ")

# reading file content line by line.
lines = file_read.readlines()

new_list = []
index = 0

# looping through each line in the file
for line in lines:
    
    # if line has the input string, get the index
    # of that line and put the
    # line into newly created list
    if text in line:
        new_list.insert(index, line)
        index +=1 

# closing file after reading
file_read.close()

# if length of new list is 0 that means
# the input string doesn't
# exist in the text file
if len(new_list)==0:
    print("\n\"" +text+ "\" is not found in \"" +file_name+ "\"!")
else:
    # displaying the lines
    # containing given string
    lineLen = len(new_list)
    print("/n**** Lines containing \"" +text+ "below / ****/n")
    for i in range(lineLen):
        print(end=new_list[i])
    print()
```

Edit:

I have started a new script and attempted to return the next line from the string I input. I don't get any result. I also get a TypeError: 'str; object is not an iterator.

```
# input file name with extension

file = input("Enter The File's Name: ")

# opening and reading the file
file_read = open(file, "r")

# asking the user to enter the string to be
# searched
text = input("Enter the String: ")

for line in file_read: 
    
    if text in line: 
        
        print(next(line))

    else:

        print("Text not found.")
```

Comment: You are only indexing the lines that contain the text. Put the index += 1 on the outer for loop and not inside the if statement and see if that works a bit better for you

Comment: Don't read all the lines in advance. Files are iterators in Python so you can just do something like: `for line in file: if text in line: print(next(file))`

Comment: use context managers (`with`), don't close the files yourself, does your program works if the input file is 2 TB large

Comment: why do you iterate over `new_list` with an index `i`, why keep `new_list`, just output each line, check if you have done some output at the end, if not display `Not Found`

Comment: what is the use of `index`, use `list.append()`

Comment: @Tomerikoo I have tried your method and I am still struggling. I wrote a new basic script and I can get the programme to loop through the file but I cannot get it to print the line beneath a string in the file.

Comment: Well it would help if you [edit] with your new attempt. Also notice the duplicate which suggests another option